# How would I create a loop that makes a new tuple for every child in a .xml file

Tags: python, arrays, xml, tuples

so for my project I am required to take an xml file, parse it in Python and then create multiple parallel arrays. I figured out how to make one big tuple that has all of the children in it. Now I just need to figure out a way to break them up into separate tuples. The easiest way I figure is to do a for loop. However, I am having trouble with this. So if I have a list of CD's and their info, I want to make a loop that takes each CD and it's info and put that in a tuple. How would I go about this?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_xml_file():
    tree = ET.parse('cd_catalog.xml')
    return tree


def get_root(tree):
    root = tree.getroot()
    return root

def find_cd(tree):
    cd = tree.findall('.//CD')
    return cd


def build_cd_array(tree,root,cd):
    for x in range(len(cd)):
        array = [tuple(c.text for c in list(cd)) for cd in     root.findall('CD')
    print(array)






def main():
    tree = get_xml_file()
    root = get_root(tree)
    cd = find_cd(tree)
    build_cd_array(tree,root,cd)


main()
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please -at least- provide some code of what you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: Are you open to solutions using other libraries besides elementtree?